# How to call onCreate of application class while running activity tests using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my Android app, I have an `Application` class which extends `MultiDexApplication`. Let's call it `MyApplicationClass` In the `onCreate()` of `MyApplicationClass.java`, I set some static variables. Then in the `onCreate()` method of all the activities I get those variables using static methods.

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication {

  private static String value;

  public static void setValue(String value) {
    MyApplicationClass.value = value;
  }

  public static String getValue() {
    return MyApplicationClass.value;
  }
}
```

Now using Espresso framework, I am writing UI tests for an activity using the following code

```
public class MyActivityTest{

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule activityTestRule =
      new ActivityTestRule(MyActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void testButtonIsVisible() {
     //Some Test code.
  }
}
```

After running the test from Android Studio, `onCreate()` method of `MyActivity` gets called and its tries to get the static variables. But the value of those variables is null. The reason is fairly simple. `onCreate()` of `MyApplicationClass.java` doesn't get called in the process.

So how do I call the `onCreate()` method of an **Application** class before launching the activity in Espresso?

P.S. Please don't advice regarding the setting and getting of static variables. That the requirement of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent a lot of time until I realized that we use a custom TestRunner and ovveride the newApplication method. Because of this during tests we used another class for the Application with an empry onCreate method. 
Once I switched to the default TestRunner the onCreate from the application was executed as expected.

```
@Override
@NonNull
public Application newApplication(@NonNull ClassLoader cl,
                                  @NonNull String className,
                                  @NonNull Context context)
        throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    return super.newApplication(cl,TestPLayerApplication.class.getName(), context);
}
```